# Snakemake doesn't infer wildcards with input function

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm trying to write a snakemake workflow that where the wildcards are 'swapped' using an input function.  Essentially, there are two conditions ('A' and 'B'), and a number of files are generated for each (`A/1.txt`, `A/2.txt`, etc, `B/1.txt`, `B/2.txt`, etc)  The number of files is always the same between the conditions, but unknown at the start of the workflow.  There is an intermediate step, and then I want to use the intermediate files from one condition with the original files from the other condition.  I wrote a simple snakefile that illustrates what I want to do:

```
dirs = ("A", "B")

wildcard_constraints:
  DIR='|'.join(dirs),
  sample='\d+'

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{DIR}_done", DIR=dirs)

checkpoint create_files:
    output:
        directory("{DIR}/")
    shell:
        """
        mkdir {output};
          N=10;
        for D in $(seq $N); do
            touch {output}/$D.txt
        done
        """

rule intermediate:
  input:
    "{DIR}/{SAMPLE}.txt"
  output:
    intermediate = "{DIR}_intermediate/{SAMPLE}.txt"
  shell:
    "touch {intermediate}"

def swap_input(wildcards):
  
  if wildcards.DIR == 'A':
    return f'B_intermediate/{wildcards.SAMPLE}.txt'
    
  if wildcards.DIR == 'B':
    return f'A_intermediate/{wildcards.SAMPLE}.txt'

rule swap:
  input:
    original = "{DIR}/{SAMPLE}.txt",
    intermediate = swap_input
  output:
    swapped="{DIR}_swp/{SAMPLE}.txt"
  shell:
    "touch {output}"

def get_samples(wildcards):

    checkpoint_dir = checkpoints.create_files.get(**wildcards).output[0]

    samples = glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "{sample}.txt")).sample
    return samples

rule done:
  input:
    lambda wildcards: expand("{DIR}_swp/{SAMPLE}.txt", SAMPLE=get_samples(wildcards), allow_missing=True)
  output:
    "{DIR}_done"
  shell:
    "touch {output}"
```

However, snakemake doesn't appear to be correctly inferring the wildcards.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding something about the way snakemake infers wildcards. I get the error:

```
MissingInputException in rule intermediate in line 38 of Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule intermediate:
    output: A_intermediate/1.txt
    wildcards: DIR=A, SAMPLE=1
    affected files:
        A/1.txt
```

But the file `A/1.txt` should be created by the first rule `create_files`.

I thought perhaps this might be something to do with the checkpoint not being completed, but if I add `checkpoint_dir = checkpoints.create_files.get(**wildcards).output[0]` at the start of the input function `swap_input`, the error is still the same.

Is there a way to get this workflow to work?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure this out - the key was that the input to rule `intermediate` had to also be conditional on the checkpoint so it's only evaluated after the checkpoint completion (otherwise snakemake doesn't know about the files `A/1.txt`, etc).

I also changed the shell directives for the rules so that we can check that the workflow is behaving as expected, and added the `-p` flag to `mkdir` in the first checkpoint as suggested by @Wayne.  The final workflow looks like this:

```
dirs = ("A", "B")

wildcard_constraints:
  DIR='|'.join(dirs),
  sample='\d+'

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{DIR}_done", DIR=dirs)

checkpoint create_files:
  output:
    directory("{DIR}/")
  shell:
    """
    mkdir -p {output}
    N=10
    for D in $(seq $N); do
      let "NUM = $D + $RANDOM"
      echo $NUM > {output}/$D.txt
    done
    """

rule intermediate:
  input:
    lambda wildcards: os.path.join(checkpoints.create_files.get(**wildcards).output[0],
                                    f"{wildcards.SAMPLE}.txt")
  output:
    "{DIR}_intermediate/{SAMPLE}.txt"
  shell:
    "cp {input} {output}"


def swap_intermediate(wildcards):
  
  if wildcards.DIR == 'A':
    return f'B_intermediate/{wildcards.SAMPLE}.txt'
    
  if wildcards.DIR == 'B':
    return f'A_intermediate/{wildcards.SAMPLE}.txt'


rule swap:
  input:
    original = "{DIR}/{SAMPLE}.txt",
    intermediate = swap_intermediate
  output:
    swapped="{DIR}_swp/{SAMPLE}.txt"
  shell:
    "cat {input.original} {input.intermediate} > {output.swapped}"


def get_samples(wildcards):

    checkpoint_dir = checkpoints.create_files.get(**wildcards).output[0]

    samples = glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "{sample}.txt")).sample
    return samples
    

rule done:
  input:
    lambda wildcards: expand("{DIR}_swp/{SAMPLE}.txt", SAMPLE=get_samples(wildcards), allow_missing=True)
  output:
    "{DIR}_done"
  shell:
    "touch {output}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern in the `output` for `create_files` though doesn't suggest it is making files, just a directory, and so when it gets to rule `intermediate`, snakemake isn't seeing the association to the input you put for rule `intermediate` and the output of `create_files`.

Also, the rule running mkdir each time was causing an error (`mkdir: cannot create directory ‘B’: File exists`) and so I separated that out. (Add ing `-p` flag to avoid that error lead to incorrect type call.) Feel like it could be combined correctly; however, I wasn't coming up with the solution.

Suggested:

```py
dirs = ("A", "B")

wildcard_constraints:
  DIR='|'.join(dirs),
  sample='\d+'
 
SAMPLE_NUMS = list(range(1,11))
#print(SAMPLE_NUMS)
#print(expand("{DIR}/{SAMPLE}.txt", SAMPLE=SAMPLE_NUMS, allow_missing=True))

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{DIR}_done", DIR=dirs)

checkpoint create_dir:
    output:
        directory("{DIR}/")
    shell:
        """
        mkdir {output}
        """

checkpoint create_files:
    output:
        expand("{DIR}/{SAMPLE}.txt", SAMPLE=SAMPLE_NUMS, allow_missing=True)
    shell:
        """
        touch {output}
        """

rule intermediate:
  input:
    "{DIR}/{SAMPLE}.txt"
  output:
    intermediate = "{DIR}_intermediate/{SAMPLE}.txt"
  shell:
    "touch {intermediate}"

def swap_input(wildcards):
  
  if wildcards.DIR == 'A':
    return f'B_intermediate/{wildcards.SAMPLE}.txt'
    
  if wildcards.DIR == 'B':
    return f'A_intermediate/{wildcards.SAMPLE}.txt'

rule swap:
  input:
    original = "{DIR}/{SAMPLE}.txt",
    intermediate = swap_input
  output:
    swapped="{DIR}_swp/{SAMPLE}.txt"
  shell:
    "touch {output}"

def get_samples(wildcards):

    checkpoint_dir = checkpoints.create_files.get(**wildcards).output[0]

    samples = glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "{sample}.txt")).sample
    return samples

rule done:
  input:
    lambda wildcards: expand("{DIR}_swp/{SAMPLE}.txt", SAMPLE=get_samples(wildcards), allow_missing=True)
  output:
    "{DIR}_done"
  shell:
    "touch {output}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  The main issue I have is that I don't know how many files  will be created in the `create_files` checkpoint at the start of the workflow, so I can't do `SAMPLE_NUMS = list(range(1,11))`.  In this example I just picked N=10, but this is a toy workflow to illustrate the issue - my actual workflow that has a lot more steps, and the number of groups in the rule analogous to `create_files` depends on the input files to the workflow.

Comment: Oh yes, you did say that would be unknown. Glad my mention of the flag helped. I think it didn't work when I tried it because I was adding in the file names to the input there.